Why is createConstraint() on my form throwing an error?
I have used constraints on 3 forms in my app. When I created my new form (the 4th to use constraints) I am getting a "cannot find symbol" on createConstraint() when I rebuild the app. I have copied the form with the required TableLayout design and the constraint setup (shown below) from the last form I completed. Any ideas?
gamep.add(t2.createConstraint().heightPercentage(40).widthPercentage(100), goals);


I tried a few changes and they did not correct the problem. I reviewed my constructor and realized I had set the constructor as:
Layout tl = new TableLayout(3, 1);

I changed the constructor to:
TableLayout tl = new TableLayout(3, 1);

This corrected the "cannot find symbol" error. Always check your constructors.
